SQL Server exclude records in Log File Viewer
Is there a way in SQL Server's Log File Viewer utility to exlude records I don't want to see? For example, if all I wanted to see were records realted to backups, I could type "Backup" in the Source field and that would be fine. What I am hoping to do is to exlude records with a Source of Backup so that I can see everything else. Is that possible with this tool? I can query xp_readerrorlog in SSMS or Get-DbaErrorLog in PowerShell, but it would be nice to do this quickly in the UI. I'm hoping there is some equivalent of NOT LIKE '%Backup%' that works in the UI.

